# Security risk in libweexjsc.so, where is the source code?

Tags: security, lib, privilege, weex

weex creates a log file with world-writable privilege inside libweexjsc.so, it's dangerous and with high risk. 
But we could not find the source code of libweexjsc.so to find a workaround.

the log file path is: /data/data/xxxxxxxx/cache/jsserver_crash/jsserver_crash_info.log

Comment: This is not the local path to my computer... It's the path inside the app where weex creates the file. And my purpose of posting this question is not to get the source code, which will be helpful if it's available, but just to solve the security problem.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. My apologies, I will retract my downvote ASAP.

Comment: aha, it's ok  :)